# pgfplots: figure too large

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I have a problem with pgfplots and it took me a while to strip down my problem to the minimum. I try to add two lines and fill the area between them. The curves have points outside of the axis area. With 'compat=newest' this results in a figure too big. With 'compat=default' the figure is clipped right at the axes.

The followig MWE shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-90,
            xmax=90,
            ymin=-90,
            ymax=90,
            ]
            \addplot[name path=A] table{
                -90     -80
                90      100
                };
            \addplot[name path=B] table{
                -90     -100
                90      80
                };
            \addplot fill between[of=A and B];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried to add some sample images, but with the white background you cannot tell the difference here. I keep trying to get feasible samples.

In this example the figure gets just slightly bigger, than expected. But in my actual file it gains about 50% in height resulting in very akward spacing.
For now I solve the problem with `compat=default`. Is there any other solution?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: hmmm i put your mwe into [sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/) and i don't see a difference between `compat=newest` and `compat=default`.  am i missing something?

Comment: [As recommended by the author of `pgfplots`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139695/32374), you should pick an explicit version, instead of using the `default` and `newest` options. In fact, if you look at the log file for the `default`, you'll find that it recommends you to add an explicit version. I can reproduce this behavior you see, but I think it is "expected" :-) There is probably some way to fix it, let's see

Comment: Yes, I saw the log entry, when using `default`. That's why I went using `newest` a long time ago. I never noticed a difference. But now I actually stumbled over a version issue. So I should reconsider and put a specific version there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior since version 1.8. We can "fix" it by setting the `clip bounding box` key, described on page 325 of the v 1.12 manual. Prior to version 1.8, the default value for this key was `default tikz`, which clipped the bounding box to the axes. Now, the default is `upper bound`, which changes the behavior as you see. The keyword `compat=default` introduces version `pre 1.3` (explained on page 11 of the v 1.12 manual), so uses the old behavior. We can restore the old behavior by simply setting the value of the appropriate key in `pgfplotsset`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12, clip bounding box=default tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-90,
            xmax=90,
            ymin=-90,
            ymax=90,
            ]
            \addplot[name path=A] table{
                -90     -80
                90      100
                };
            \addplot[name path=B] table{
                -90     -100
                90      80
                };
            \addplot fill between[of=A and B];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked very well. It seems, that everything is contained in the pgfplots documentation. You just need to know, what you are looking for. I need to read the section about the clip bounding box again. By now I have not yet understood the advantages of `upper bound`.