# pgfplots: Fixing overlapping X axis labels

Tags: pgfplots, labels, ticks, dateplot

I am trying to create a time series plot but my `X` axis labels overlap:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{width=14cm,compat=newest}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}     

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
count  date
38  2015-01-28
5  2015-02-11
21  2015-02-15
1  2015-02-16
21  2015-02-17
21  2015-02-18
62  2015-02-19
16  2015-02-25
4  2015-02-26
1  2015-02-30
1  2015-03-07
44  2015-04-07
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{data.csv}\table
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in = x,
    date ZERO = 2015-01-28,
    ymin = 0,
    x tick label style = {font = \small, text width = 1.7cm, align = center, rotate = 70, anchor = north east},
    xtick = data,
    xticklabels from table = \table{date}
    ]
\addplot [only marks, blue] table [x = date, y = count] \table;%
\addplot [green] table [x = date, y = count] \table;%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Removing the `xtick = data,` line fixes the overlapping problem, but the blue dots and the ticks on the `X` axis do not line up anymore.

How to have the `X` axis labels in constant distances? I also tried `xticklabel style={inner sep=0pt, anchor=north east, rotate=70}` but it did not fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work. I removed the `dateplot` stuff, and instead of `x=date` for the `\addplot`, I used `x expr=\coordindex`. This uses the index of the coordinate instead, i.e. 0,1,2,..., which gives constant distance between ticks. `xtick=data` places the ticks at the right place. You do need to load `pgfplotstable` to use `x expr=\coordindex`.

As a sidenote, `compat=newest` isn't necessarily a good thing, see [Dos and Don'ts of \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139690/dos-and-donts-of-pgfplotssetcompat-newest/139695#139695)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{width=14cm,compat=1.12}     

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
count  date
38  2015-01-28
5  2015-02-11
21  2015-02-15
1  2015-02-16
21  2015-02-17
21  2015-02-18
62  2015-02-19
16  2015-02-25
4  2015-02-26
1  2015-02-30
1  2015-03-07
44  2015-04-07
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{data.csv}\data
\begin{axis}[
    ymin = 0,
    x tick label style = {font = \small, text width = 1.7cm, align = center, rotate = 70, anchor = north east},
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table = \data{date}
    ]
\addplot [green,mark=*, mark options={blue}] table [x expr=\coordindex, y = count] \data;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```