# How to draw a function like sin(x)~cos(x) in tikz/pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, r

In R it's easy to do something like

```
x <- seq(0, 2*pi, 0.01)
plot(sin(x), cos(3*x), type='line')
```

to get the plot

[image]

How can I make such a plot using tikz/pgfplots?

Comment: Might be an idea to explain the `~` syntax you use in the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is also easy with `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[domain=0:360,samples=101,no marks] ({sin(x)},{cos(3*x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd say: *easier and prettier*.

Comment: +1 . Since this is an answer to a beginner question, I would like to advertise that `\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad}` in the preamble would reconfigure all plots to use radians. In this case, one could also write `domain=0:2*pi` to get the same outcome.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Also may I suggest an alias for the `compat` key as `assume version` or somoething along those lines? That would make the users aware that there are compatibility options and also `assume version=newest` becomes a literal.

Comment: In principle: yes... but I am not sure if I want to substitute its occurrences in all examples. But that, in turn, would be necessary in order to make people aware of its existence. [...]

Comment: [...] And if they are not aware of it, it will add confusion rather than clarification, especially since `compat` is an established best-practise and people are used to it. And since `assume version=newest` sounds as if that would be a good idea, I would even more say that I would rather discourage people from it and not at the alias (newest is often a bad idea, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139690/dos-and-donts-of-pgfplotssetcompat-newest/139695#139695). With this reasoning, I would rather not follow the suggestion. If in doubt, let us discuss it by email.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Probably, I wasn't clear. I didn't mean to replace `compat`. I was thinking along the lines of `no marks` and `no markers` situation. I don't think you should replace anything because it is well established. I'll think about it a little more on this. For the `newest`, I agree it is a little bit abused by the newcomers.