# pgfplots: Dancing ylabel when Using '\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}' and 'extra y ticks'

Tags: pgfplots

- I want to use `extra y ticks` in a `pgfplots` diagram.
- With `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` the `ylabel` is dancing (not watnted).

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % <-- Causes dancing y label when adding  'extra y ticks'

\pgfplotsset{myDefaultStyle/.style = 
    {
    width = 160mm,
    height = 90mm,
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    ylabel = y Label,
    xlabel = x Label,   
    grid = major,
    }}

\begin{document}

% ######### Plot #########
% ########################
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        myDefaultStyle,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 32,
        ymin = 24.5,
        ymax = 30.1,        
        xtick = {0,10,20,30},   
        ytick = {25,26,30},     
    ]
    % Plots 
    \addplot[domain=0:10,red]{x^2};     
    %   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% ######### Plot #########
% ########################
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        myDefaultStyle,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 32,
        ymin = 24.5,
        ymax = 30.1,        
        xtick = {0,10,20,30},   
        ytick = {25,26,30},     
        extra y ticks={25.5}, % <-- Added
    ]
    % Plots     
    \addplot[domain=0:10,red]{x^2}; 
    %
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

### With `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`

[image]

### Without `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest]`

[image]

Comment: See section 2.2.1 in the manual, item 14 about version 1.3.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks! You mean `pgfplots 1.3 has a new feature which allows to move axis labels tight to tick labels automatically.
This is strongly recommended. It requires \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3} or higher.
Since this affects the spacing, it is not enabled be default.`?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. I don't know exactly what you're asking, so I pointed to an explanation of why that occurs.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Do you know a way to avoid this (else then not using `compat=newest`)?

Comment: Try `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14,compat/labels=default}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in section 2.2.2 of the manual, it's possible to set the `compat` version for specific features, which are described in section  2.2.1, so for your case you can do

```
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  compat/labels=default
}
```

to go back to the default setting for axis labels.

Addendum: [Dos and Don'ts of \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139690/dos-and-donts-of-pgfplotssetcompat-newest)