# pgfplots: Where do I find information what the newest version is (for `\pgfplotsset{compat=x.y}`)?

Tags: pgfplots

- I really tried to solve this question on my own: I must have missed the obvious answer.
- One can use `\pgfplotsset{compat=x.y}` to set used version of `pgfplots`.
- I thought that the version that is stated on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?) or the manual cover page is the version that I can use within `\pgfplotsset{compat=x.y}`.
- But apparently, I am mistaken since the current version on CTAN is labeled `1.18.1` but I can use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}` in my document.
- **Question:** Where does a *naive* user (meaning: no solution that requires looking at a log file) find out what is the newest version of `pgfplots` without using `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139690/)).

[image]

---

**Update:** I was stupid and confused `1.18` with `1.1.8`! Thanks to user **CarLaTeX** for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your document without `\pgfplotsset{compat=...}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot{x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the log you will get:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} into 
your preamble.
 on input line 4.
```

The newest version is the one suggested in the log: `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}`.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I used before but I needed to upgrade to `1.8` in order to use a specific feature. This is what made me wonder.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Sorry, I don't understand why you don't use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}`, then.

Comment: I want to use (explicitly select) the most current version without using the `newest` option, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139690/.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The newest is `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}`, I have updated my TeX Live this morning.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But why can I use `1.8` or `1.9`? Isn't `1.8 > 1.18`? The manual also mentioned `1.3` etc.

Comment: Wait a sec.-- maybe I am stupid! I confused `1.18` with `1.1.8`!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner No, 1.8 is < 1.18 because it's not a decimal point, it's a version.subversion. Version 1 subversion 8 is less than version 1 subversion 18.

Comment: Sorry for that. The confusion was that I needed to change from `1.18` to `1.8` in order to get a simple example running and that is why I assumed that `1.8` must be newer.

Comment: The `tikzpicture` is actually not necessary in your example, the warning comes anyway. In addition, `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{pgfplots} \begin{document} \pgfplotsversion \end{document}` can be used to print the version number in the PDF.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I didn't know that, feel free to add your answer. Thank you.