# How can I decrease space between y-axis label and its line using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot as compact as possible using `pgfplots`.

I have the following piece of code:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
            width=7.5cm,
            xlabel={Size of the data set list},
            ylabel={Gas cost},
            grid=major,
            domain=1:100,
            xmin=0,xmax=10,
            ymin=0,ymax=10,
            ytick={0,2,...,12},
            samples=21,
        ]
        \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the following output:

[image]

I don't know why but there is extra new-line between the y-axis's label and its line. How can I remove the extra-space between y-axis's label and y-axis line?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem (tested by `pgfplots` version 1.18). You can define `y label style` with smaller `inner sep`, for example `inner sep=1pt`.

Comment: @Zarko That is because of the compat setting. Any compat setting of 1.3 or higher activates a better method for placing axis labels.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I believe I was using `\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}` should I use `1.3` instead of `newest`

Comment: @alper I didn't say that, I said that any valid option for `compat` with a version number higher than 1.3 will improve the position of the y-axis label. I would probably use the setting corresponding to the `pgfplots` version you have installed, so if you're up to date, that is `compat=1.18`. (By the way,  `latest` isn't a valid option for `compat`. There is a `newest` option, but it is not recommended to use that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139690/)

Comment: (The comment above was written before I saw that you edited your comment.)

Comment: When I checkted the log file current installed version for `pgfplots ` is `v1.18.1`, hence `compat=1.18` is used. But still the extra space remains :-(

Comment: No, the installed version and the compat setting are not the same. You need to actually have the codeline `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` in your document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your installed version is `v1.18.1`, you have to set the `compat` option explicitly to request that all features of version 1.18 are used. If you omit it, you get the following warning in the log:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode
(unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} into your preamble. on input line 4.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
            width=7.5cm,
            xlabel={Size of the data set list},
            ylabel={Gas cost},
            grid=major,
            domain=1:100,
            xmin=0,xmax=10,
            ymin=0,ymax=10,
            ytick={0,2,...,12},
            samples=21,
        ]
        \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I never check the log file that has the compilation output, next time I should :-)