# How to plot a Hyperbolic paraboloid in a style of the attached figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

How to plot a Hyperbolic paraboloid in a style of the attached figure using only one COLOUR [image]

Modify my Code please

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            zlabel=$z$,
            view={60}{30},
        ]
        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, domain=-2:2, samples=41] 
            {x^2/4 - y^2/9};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Hyperbolic Paraboloid: $z = \frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{y^2}{9}$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does "white" count as a color?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Assuming white is not a color

Comment: @JohnKormylo Please suggest how to plot it

Comment: I think that `addplot3` with `surf` draws the graph of a function defined on a rectangle.  In your attached image, the surface is such a graph but with the `Oz` axis clipped.  I don't know if this is possible with `addplot3`.  In case it is not and you really need that type of representation, I guess you have to do it directly in TikZ where you control the domain of the parametrization (for example the y domain will depend of each x in the x domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

One solution would be to split the paraboloid in two, to achieve  some sort of layering.  I did the same thing with the coordinate axes.

I modified the code according to @hpekristiansen kind remark concerning the compatibility of the coordinate systems of `pdfplots` and `tikz`.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{set layers}
  \begin{axis}view={150}{12}, axis lines=none]
    \addplot3[
    surf,
    colormap/cool,
    shader=flat,
    opacity=.6,
    domain=-4:4,
    domain y=-4:0,
    samples=40,
    clip=false
    ] {x^2 -y^2};

    % plane section x = 0
    \addplot3[%
    draw=blue, very thin,
    fill=red, fill opacity=.15,
    domain=-4:4,
    samples y=0
    ] (0, x, {-x^2});

    \draw[ultra thin, ->] (0, 0, 0) -- (6, 0, 0)
    node[below, text=black, scale=.8] {$x$};

    \addplot3[
    surf,
    colormap/cool,
    shader=flat,
    opacity=.6,
    domain=-4:4,
    domain y=0:4,
    samples=40,
    clip=false
    ] {x^2 -y^2};

    \addplot3[%
    draw=blue, very thin,
    domain=0:4,
    samples y=0
    ] (0, x, {-x^2});

    \draw[ultra thin, ->] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 0, 18)
    node[above, text=black, scale=.8] {$z$};
    \draw[ultra thin, ->] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 6, 0)
    node[below, text=black, scale=.8] {$y$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Remember to always set the `compat` level when using PGFPlots. Do not use explicit `axis cs:` -it is the default coordinate system since many versions ago.

Comment: Thank you @hpekristiansen  I shall try your indications tonight to see if I understand them correctly.  If I use, say `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.??}`, then I can write `\draw (0, 0, 0) ...` instead of `\draw (axis cs: 0, 0, 0) ...`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes - exactly. Use preferably `1.18` if your system is up to date or a version not too old. If you do not you get a warning when you compile. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139695/8650

Answer (score 0):

The image you show does not match the hyperboloid calculated.

See section 5.2 (page 425) of the pgfplots manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            zlabel=$z$,
            view={60}{30},
            colormap/PuBu-9
            ]
        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, domain=-2:2, samples=41] 
            {x^2/4 - y^2/9};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Hyperbolic Paraboloid: $z = \frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{y^2}{9}$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to reproduce the above Fig that I have attached. It will help me to plot other Figs of conicoids or quadrics. Please help...

Comment: You can do a lot by changing the viewing angles, and reversing the signs.  The shown image is not using an orthogonal 3D grid either. (the y axis should be sloped, or the x axis should point directly to the POV).