Make each color from colormap darker in pgfplots
I'm using pgfplots to draw a figure with multiple plots/curves, which I colour from the Greens colormap from ColorBrewer. The problem is the colours are too "light" and I want to darken each colour somehow. How can I do that automatically? I may change the colormap later, so it should be code that works for every colormap if possible. Is there an easy way? Below is the code I currently use.
            \begin{axis}[
                legend pos=north east,
                grid=both,
                xmin=-1,
                xmax=1,
                width=\textwidth,
                colormap/Greens, 
                cycle list={[of colormap]},
            ]


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

The question didn't specify how many curves are expected in each plot. If it is not too many then you can start the colormap later, instead of at Greens-A (which is a very light green) you can start at Greens-F for example.
If you have more curves then you can darken them by appending !75!Greens-K in the colormap definition, which means "75% of the original color and 25% Greens-K" (the second darkest Green), effectively darkening the color.
This can be automated by creating new commands that take the colormap name as an argument and defining new colormaps based on those. In the code below you could write for example \makedarksub{Blues} or \makedarkfull{Purples} to make the colormaps BluesDarkSub and PurplesDarkFull available.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makedarksub}[1]{%
\pgfplotsset{%
/pgfplots/colormap/#1DarkSub/.style={
    colormap={#1DarkSub}{
      color=(#1-F);
      color=(#1-G);
      color=(#1-H);
      color=(#1-I);
      color=(#1-J);
      color=(#1-K);
      color=(#1-L);
      color=(#1-M);
    },
    cycle list/.define={#1DarkSub}{[of colormap=#1DarkSub]},
  },
  /pgfplots/cycle list/#1DarkSub/.style={/pgfplots/@@brewer set cycle list={#1DarkSub}}
}
}

\newcommand{\makedarkfull}[1]{%
\pgfplotsset{%
/pgfplots/colormap/#1DarkFull/.style={
    colormap={#1DarkFull}{
      color=(#1-A!75!#1-K);
      color=(#1-C!75!#1-K);
      color=(#1-D!75!#1-K);
      color=(#1-F!75!#1-K);
      color=(#1-G!75!#1-K);
      color=(#1-H!75!#1-K);
      color=(#1-J!75!#1-K);
      color=(#1-K!75!#1-K);
      color=(#1-M!75!#1-K);
    },
    cycle list/.define={#1DarkFull}{[of colormap=#1DarkFull]},
  },
  /pgfplots/cycle list/#1DarkFull/.style={/pgfplots/@@brewer set cycle list={#1DarkFull}}
}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Original

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
                legend pos=north east,
                grid=both,
                xmin=-1,
                xmax=1,
                width=8cm,
                colormap/Greens, 
                cycle list={[of colormap]},
            ]
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{2*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{3*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{4*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{5*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{6*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{7*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{8*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{9*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Subset starting at Greens--F\hskip4cm Full colormap with 25\% Greens--K\par
\makedarksub{Greens}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
                legend pos=north east,
                grid=both,
                xmin=-1,
                xmax=1,
                width=8cm,
                colormap/GreensDarkSub, 
                cycle list={[of colormap]},
            ]
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{2*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{3*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{4*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{5*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\makedarkfull{Greens}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
                legend pos=north east,
                grid=both,
                xmin=-1,
                xmax=1,
                width=8cm,
                colormap/GreensDarkFull, 
                cycle list={[of colormap]},
            ]
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{2*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{3*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{4*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{5*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{6*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{7*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{8*x};
\addplot+[line width=5pt]{9*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Result:


+1 Remember to set the compat level when using PGFPlots.

@hpekristiansen I actually think the compat feature has limited usefulness. In his answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139695/ Christian Feuersänger argues that you don't want to check a large number of plots for correctness when recompiling an old document, but in my experience the vast majority of documents (a) does not have a large number of plots and (b) is never recompiled after it is completed/published/presented. Of course if you are the author of a textbook with a new edition every few years then the feature is very helpful and you should use it, but otherwise [...]

[...] it is not really needed. Conversely, when you reuse for example axis settings for a new document with a graph similar to an older one then you may be interested in using new syntax and/or new features, and you will inspect the result anyway, so you will most likely ignore the compat setting of the original document. And in the (rather unlikely) event that you copy an old figure to a new document and it doesn't work anymore then you can probably quickly figure out what the most recent syntax is and update the code.

Exactly the link you provide expalins why you should always give the compat level(unless you for some obscure reason wish to run in ancient mode) and hard code it to a specific level - do not use newest.

@hpekristiansen I have read the link, but (as I tried to explain above) the only argument I could find there is that it guarantees the results of recompiling older documents and thereby avoiding unwanted changes in output to go undetected, which I argued is not a common usage scenario.

Wonderful, thank you.

@BBB for next time, as indicated in the comment below the question, please provide a complete example yourself. This means everything that I have written except the \newcommand definitions (and maybe only one plot instead of three). Now I had to do almost everything myself, which takes time that could have been avoided if you had provided the document, and it required some guesses on what you were trying to do which could change the solution.

@Marijn But consider that the code in your answers on this site may be compiled in a few years again and people may wonder why things break. This is exactly what setting compat would prevent. But well, your code runs without setting compat anyways, so it is unlikely to break in the future … that’s also true.
